# Generate data from firstname into initials in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is in MSSQL.
I need to generate initials. The source data has no initials, so I want to generate initials out of the first names.

`Firstname` (source data) is 100 characters. I pass this to a function that shortens it and spits back 50 characters. The destination field for initials is max 15 characters, so I then grab the `LEFT(..., 15)`.

I have created a function to handle & and commas however depending on the order of & and commas, the result of the function drops a letter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Strip_to_Initials_failed_Try1]
     (@string NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retrieval NVARCHAR(100);

    SET @string = RTRIM(LTRIM(@string));
    SET @retrieval = LEFT(@string, 1);

    -- Step 1: get non space character after & symbol
    WHILE CHARINDEX('&', @string, 1) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @string = LTRIM(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX('&', @string, 1)));
        SET @retrieval += '&' + LEFT(@string, 1);
    END

    -- Step 2: get non space character after commas
    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @string, 1) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @string = LTRIM(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(',', @string, 1)));
        SET @retrieval += '&' + LEFT(@string, 1);
    END

    -- Step 4: get non space character after /
    WHILE CHARINDEX('/', @string, 1) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @string = LTRIM(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX('/', @string, 1)));
        SET @retrieval += '&' + LEFT(@string, 1);
    END

    -- Step 8: uppercase the string
    SET @retrieval = UPPER(@retrieval);

    RETURN @retrieval;
END
GO;


SELECT 
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob & Marline'),'&', ' & '),',',', '), 15),
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob , Marline'),'&', ' & '),',',', '),15),
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob & Marline & John'), '&', ' & '), ',', ', '), 15),
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob , Marline , John'),'&', ' & '),',',', '), 15),
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob & Marline , John'),'&', ' & '),',',', '),15),
    LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials('Bob , Marline & John'),'&', ' & '),',',', '),15)
```

I expect the following results:

```
B & M
B & M
B & M & J
B & M & J
B & M & J
B & M & J
```

Actual results:

```
B & M
B & M
B & M & J
B & M & J
B & M & J
B & J



----------
--04/05/2019 - see below for solution (I have made a modification to John Cappelletti's solution)
------------
--note - the below is programmed to return up to 7 characters. Including 1st charater + each other character will take up 4 characters. EG ' & A' initial consumes 4 characters.
-- 1 + (4*3)= 13 characters. Trying to return 15 charaters would bring me the data:
--'A & B & C & D &'
--in my scenario, the field only accepts 15 characters into 'initials' 
--secondly, I want to NOT create initials when there are Firstnames like 'Bob And Jane' hence the CASE
--so I am calling the function with:
CASE
    WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME))) = 0 THEN NULL 
    WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) LIKE '% %' 
        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%&%' 
        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%,%' 
        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%/%'
        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%\%'
    THEN NULL
    ELSE LEFT(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials(FIRSTNAME),13)
END AS Initials
--
--
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Strip_to_Initials] (@string NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN (
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(Pos1,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos2,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos3,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos4,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos5,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos6,1)
             ,' & ' +LEFT(Pos7,1)
       )
 FROM  (VALUES ( UPPER ( REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(@string,',','&')
                 ,'/','&')
                 ,'\','&')
               ) )
       )A(S)
 CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT Pos1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos2 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos3 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos4 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos5 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos6 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos7 = LTRIM(RTRIM(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
        FROM  ( VALUES (CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(S,'&','§§Split§§') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML)))  A(xDim)
       ) B
)
END
```

Comment: These things are difficult to pull off unless the data is very standardized. In real life, names have spaces, punctuation, and all kinds of craziness (as a legitimate part of the name).

Comment: yes, with this in mind I was only going to grab the first letter, the first letter following any ampersand(s), and the first letter following any comma(s).
I was not going to grab any letters following a space, as there is often (space ampsand word)

Comment: please provide sample data in table form or `DDL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using a `CROSS APPLY` and a little `XML`.  This can be converted into a UDF if really necessary

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int, FullName varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'Bob & Marline')
,(2,'Bob & Marline & John')
,(3,'Bob , Marline & John')


Select A.*
      ,Initial = concat(left(Pos1,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos2,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos3,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos4,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos5,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos6,1)
                       ,' & ' +left(Pos7,1)
                       )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(FullName,',','&'),'&','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
id  FullName                Initial
1   Bob & Marline           B & M
2   Bob & Marline & John    B & M & J
3   Bob , Marline & John    B & M & J    -- added and corrected
```

> **EDIT - As a Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Strip_to_Initials] (@string NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

Return (
Select concat(left(Pos1,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos2,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos3,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos4,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos5,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos6,1)
             ,' & ' +left(Pos7,1)
       )
 From  (values ( replace(
                 replace(
                 replace(@string,',','&')
                 ,'/','&')
                 ,'\','&')
               ) 
       )A(S)
 Cross Apply (
        Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
              ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
        From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(S,'&','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
       ) B
)

End
```

**Usage**

```
Select [dbo].[fn_Strip_to_Initials]( 'Bob & Marline \ John')
```

**Returns**

```
B & M & J
```

Comment: The first section seems to work, how can I add additional charaters? Such as '/' to capture the initals following either '&' or ',' or '/' ?

The function section was unclear. Was this MSSQL? Is this the entire function or should I add this to to bottom of my existing function?

Comment: Not at my desk.  You will need to add an inner replace(...,'/','&').   The bottom portion can be in your UDF.

Comment: I am unable to get the function to work; 'Select Initial = ...' returns an error that select statments included within a function cannot return data to a client. If i change this to 'SET @S =.....' the query becomes unhappy with the FROM area.
As I am limited on Characters in the comment section, please see the top post '--edit' for were I am trying to create the function

Comment: @ClientRelations See EDIT added a full function

Comment: John Cappelletti, works well.
I have made a modification to your solution. I have include UPPER to return the intials in upper case.

The solution is programmed to return up to 7 characters. 
The 1st charater returns 1 character + each other character will take up 4 characters. 
EG ' & A' initial consumes 4 characters.

In my scenario, the field only accepts 15 characters into 'initials' so I am calling the function with:
LEFT(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials(FirstName),13 AS Initials
1 + (4*3)= 13 characters. Trying to return 15 charaters would bring me the data:
'A & B & C & D &'

Comment: I should also add, I am excluding the initials in certain scenarios. If there is a firstname like 'Bob And Jane' I want to not create initials. So I call the function with:    CASE
     WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME))) = 0 THEN NULL 
     WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) LIKE '% %' 
      AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%&%' 
      AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%,%' 
      AND LTRIM(RTRIM(FIRSTNAME)) NOT LIKE '%/%' THEN NULL
     ELSE LEFT(dbo.fn_Strip_to_Initials_22(FIRSTNAME),13)
    END AS Initials